# Configuring nginx as a forward proxy with many concurrent connections

Tags: linux, nginx, http-proxy

I am not able to handle many simultaneous active connections. For 1,000 active connections Network I/O reaches about 1 Gb/s, however after increasing active connection count by double, the Network I/O drops by half. In both cases handled requests per second is very low, and testing with browser each site is loaded at least in 30 second time. CPU and RAM is hardly used, it has got to be a configuration issue.

The question is:
How do I achieve high Network I/O with a lot of active connections and handle a lot of requests per second

Current nginx configuration:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 40000;

events {
        use epoll;
        worker_connections 5000;
        multi_accept on;
}

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 30;
        keepalive_requests 1000;
        client_body_timeout 10;
        send_timeout 2;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_tokens off;
        proxy_cache_path  /data/nginx/cache  levels=1:2    keys_zone=STATIC:10m    inactive=24h  max_size=1g;
        aio threads=default;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        access_log off;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 5000;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        client_header_buffer_size 5k;
        open_file_cache max=10000 inactive=30s;
        open_file_cache_valid    60s;
        open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
        open_file_cache_errors   on;


        server {

            listen      80 default_server;
            server_name  proxy;
            server_tokens off;

            error_log  /var/log/nginx/proxy-error.log;

            error_page 502 /50x.html;

            location = /50x.html {
                    root /etc/nginx/custom_error_pages;
                    internal;
            }

            keepalive_timeout 10;
            proxy_set_header  Host  $host;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";

            proxy_set_header X-REALIP   $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_buffering    off;
            proxy_intercept_errors off;
            proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

            proxy_buffer_size  5m;
            proxy_buffers 100  10m;

            proxy_connect_timeout       600;
            proxy_send_timeout          600;
            proxy_read_timeout          600;
            send_timeout                600;


           location / {
                proxy_pass $scheme://$http_host$request_uri;
                proxy_cache            STATIC;
                proxy_cache_valid      200  1d;
                proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating  http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

            }
    }
}
```

Current sysctl.conf:

```
# Increase size of file handles and inode cache
fs.file-max = 2097152

# Do less swapping
vm.swappiness = 10
vm.dirty_ratio = 60
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 2

### GENERAL NETWORK SECURITY OPTIONS ###

# Number of times SYNACKs for passive TCP connection.
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 2

# Allowed local port range
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 2000 65535

# Protect Against TCP Time-Wait
net.ipv4.tcp_rfc1337 = 1

# Decrease the time default value for tcp_fin_timeout connection
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 15

# Decrease the time default value for connections to keep alive
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 300
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 5
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 15

### TUNING NETWORK PERFORMANCE ###

# Default Socket Receive Buffer
net.core.rmem_default = 31457280

# Maximum Socket Receive Buffer
net.core.rmem_max = 12582912

# Default Socket Send Buffer
net.core.wmem_default = 31457280

# Maximum Socket Send Buffer
net.core.wmem_max = 12582912

# Increase number of incoming connections
net.core.somaxconn = 65536

# Increase number of incoming connections backlog
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 65536

# Increase the maximum amount of option memory buffers
net.core.optmem_max = 25165824

# Increase the maximum total buffer-space allocatable
# This is measured in units of pages (4096 bytes)
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 65536 131072 662144
net.ipv4.udp_mem = 65536 131072 662144

# Increase the read-buffer space allocatable
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 8192 87380 16777216
net.ipv4.udp_rmem_min = 16384

# Increase the write-buffer-space allocatable
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 8192 65536 16777216
net.ipv4.udp_wmem_min = 16384

# Increase the tcp-time-wait buckets pool size to prevent simple DOS attacks
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 1440000
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
```

Current limits.conf:

```
* soft nofile 65536
* hard nofile 65536
```

Hardware Information: 8GB RAM, 4 Cores, Ubuntu

Additional Information:
I am firing requests through the proxy to 3 different size files 1mb, 2mb and 5mb